# In-Reply-To Header Field is Empty

Tags: email

I am investigating an email my company sent out to a client which was a big jumbled mess of seeming random letters.

We are using outlook 2016, not sure what the client uses. The email body consists of the X-CNFS-Analysis (CloudMark spam analysis), the header for the email, then random letters and numbers creating walls of text.

This only happens when we send emails to people using Hotmail and it does not happen every time.

One thing I did notice is that the `In-Reply-To` field is empty, where as from reading the RFC=2822 the `In-Reply-To` should contain the Message-ID.

Has anyone ever experienced this? Or does anyone know what would happen if the `In-Reply-To` field is left blank when a reply is sent out?

Comment: I am closing this because it is about email and not about your website.